# How to fix this error:The intent the app is asking for permission to send updates for is empty

Tags: javascript, push-notification, actions-on-google

I am trying to build an action on google which sends push notifications to the user but whenever I ask permission from the user to send updates.I encounter this error:

> expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0].input_value_data: The intent
>   the app is asking for permission to send updates for is empty.

I don't understand what does this mean since I am entirely new to this.Can someone please explain me why this is occurring and tell me the solution.

This is the code I am using to ask for permission:

```
new Permission({
    context: 'I need you to permit me to send updates ',
    permissions: 'UPDATE',
    updatePermissionValueSpec:{
    intent:'Add_Birthday'   
}
```

Comment: Is this the code you're sending? It doesn't appear to be syntactically valid.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have got the answer.Instead of using 'Permission' I am using 'UpdatePermission' and also I have enabled user engagement in the AoG console.I am using the intent name mentioned in the action section of AoG console.It seems that dialogflow recognizes that intent name.